# Reason/meaning of dot/dash pattern in Orion capsule

Tags: spacecraft-development, orion-spacecraft, artemis-program

On the interior pictures of the Orion capsule there is a distinct pattern visible above the Callisto tech demo console:

[image: Inside the Orion capsule]
*Source: [NASA](https://www.flickr.com/photos/nasa2explore/52512794774/in/album-72177720303788800/), highlight by me*

What is the reason/meaning of this pattern?

My searching the web didn't turn up anything useful that's why I'm hoping for a bit of insight from the more knowledgeable people here.

**Edit:**

User *The Rocket fan* hinted that it might be morse code. It decodes to **CHARLIE** when read forward to aft of the capsule. But why?

Comment: It looks like Morse code

Comment: Oh, you are right! Read from spacecraft front to aft it reads "CHARLIE" – but why?

Comment: Charlie Blackwell-Thompson..?

Comment: Wild speculation - an allusion to 'Charlie Brown' & Apollo 10?

Comment: Similar, but much more subtle, is the message in Perseverance's parachute: https://www.livescience.com/nasa-perseverance-rover-parachute-secret-code.html  It was done mostly just because they could.

Comment: https://www.reddit.com/r/space/comments/z1iy2t/hidden_binary_message_inside_orion_capsule_easter/

Comment: @Andrew: interestingly, [Snoopy is floating in the picture](https://www.bbc.com/news/av/science-environment-63711200). He's near the center, wearing an orange suit.

Comment: @Andrew it is indeed.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Tribute to former (deceased) Orion chief engineer Charlie Lundquist.

> Located above the Callisto voice-activated technology demonstration in the middle of the cabin, a morse code symbol for “Charlie” commemorates the life of former Orion Deputy Program Manager Charlie Lundquist, who died in 2020. Lundquist worked in the Orion Program between 2008 and his passing, playing an instrumental role in Orion’s development.

https://www.nasa.gov/feature/hidden-messages-pay-tribute-inside-nasa-s-artemis-i-orion-spacecraft